# Как реализовать триггер в консоли (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, консоль

Имеется такой вот запрос на добавление триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
```

Но, при использовании консоли каждая кома с запятой является завершением запроса. Вопрос: *Что делать, если хочу писать триггер в консоли? Спасибо.*

Answer (score 6):

Нужно поменять разделитель команд. Например:

```
> DELIMITER //
> CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
      DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
      UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
    END//
> DELIMITER ;
```